# count letters and occurence in percent

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using the following function to count the occurrence of letters of a given string:

```
def count(text):
    dicti = {}
    for sent in text:
        for letter in sent:
            if letter.isalpha():
                if letter in dicti.keys():
                    dicti[letter]+=1
                else:
                    dicti[letter] = 1
    print(dicti)

count("Hello World")
```

That generates the output:

```
{'H': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 3, 'o': 2, 'W': 1, 'r': 1, 'd': 1}
```

I now would like to take that result and would like to calculate the occurrence of these letters in percent, also with the letters which do not occur in the string. And put it in a list:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0.1, 0.1, ..... ]
 a  b  c   d    e   ..... (do not list the letters)
```

I've added the following lines to my code above:

```
    print(dicti)
    list=[]
    list.insert(dicti)
    print(list(dicti))
```

My goal is to put the output in a list and then apply the percentage formula.

Is that the right way? However, I get that error:

```
TypeError: insert() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: now what is the problem? You know how to calculate percent, right?

Comment: sorry, did I use a wrong tag?

Comment: "Hello World" contains 10 letters in total; letter d for example occurs one time. formula is 100/10 in that case. I think I'm struggling to how format and create that list

Comment: You've posted some code, but nothing which attempts to do what you are asking about (calculate percentage)

Comment: yes I don't know how to take the result and take it into a percentage function and I don't know how to put the result into a list

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a correct frequency dictionary. But there is a simpler way (which will also have a benefit later). You can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to reduce some (*all?*) of the logic:

```py
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter(text)
```

If you want to ignore spaces you can do a quick modification:

```
counter = Counter(c for c in text if c.isalpha())
```

And this is all you need for the frequencies. If printing `counter` you'll get:

```
Counter({'l': 3, 'o': 2, 'H': 1, 'e': 1, 'W': 1, 'r': 1, 'd': 1})
```

Now to create the list you want of the percentage of all letters we need to get all letters and the total. The letters can be taken from the [`string`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters) module, and the total also becomes easy when using a `Counter`. As simple as [`counter.total()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.total)!<sup>[1]</sup>

The last handy thing about a `Counter` is you can access elements that are not even there! They will return 0 by default. So to put it all together:

```py
from string import ascii_letters
from collections import Counter

text = "Hello World"
counter = Counter(c for c in text if c.isalpha())

total = counter.total()
res = []
for letter in ascii_letters:
    res.append(counter[letter] / total)

print(res)
```

Gives:

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.1, 0.1, ...
```

If you want to *"normalize"* the count of lower/capital letters, you can change the counter to `c for c in text.lower()` or `text.upper()` and then use `ascii_lowercase` or `ascii_uppercase` respectively in the loop.

---

[1] - `total` is only available from Python 3.10. For earlier versions, it's possible to do [`len(list(counter.elements()))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.elements) or `sum(counter.values())` instead.

Comment: Hi Tomerikoo, I get: AttributeError: 'Counter' object has no attribute 'total'

Comment: Sorry @mountain_climber that method was introduced in Python 3.10. See my edit for two alternatives for earlier versions

Answer (score 0):

1. Setup a dictionary with all the default values of 0% for all alphabetical characters, including both lowercase, and uppercase.
2. I removed the extra for loop, because it was redundant, so instead we keep track of the alphabetical characters using a variable and increments.
3. At the end, we loop through the keys, and set the percentage using the formula `percentage = number of characters of type "x" divided by total number of characters`

```py
def count(text):
    dicti = {i:0 for i in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"}
    total = 0
    for letter in text:
      if letter.isalpha():
          if letter in dicti.keys():
              dicti[letter]+=1
          else:
              dicti[letter] = 1
          total += 1

    for key in dicti.keys():
        dicti[key] = dicti[key]/total
    return dicti

print(count("Hello World")) # dictionary with all the key value pairs for the percentage occurrences
print(count("Hello World").values()) # list of percentages from a -> z, and A -> Z respectively
```

Comment: Your code does not work. Did you mean to return the value and not print it in the function?

Comment: Yes my thinking is to return the result of the function, take that result and take it into another function which does the formula. the formula itself isn't my issue, but rather how to transfer result into a next function

Comment: Hi Anonymous, is there a way to add lower function to convert all uppercase letters to lowercase letters, I tried to inset "text.lower() between the total statement and the first for loop. Furthermore I removed the uppercase letters in dicti variable. That doesn't work though.

Comment: Hi Anonymous, got it working. Howver, your last line, I get an error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: @mountain_climber oops my bad, i just added the last line by mistake, but i'll edit my response.